# Updating DNS records

Tags: hosting, godaddy

I'm trying to migrate a WordPress site from GoDaddy to WPEngine. Sites on WPEngine are hosted at [sitename].wpengine.com. Importantly, the IP address for the site maps to a landing page instead of your actual content. In other words, if I run `ping [sitename].wpengine.com` I get an IP address. When I put that IP Address back into my browser, I see a landing page instead of my wordpress site. But, if I visit [sitename].wpengine.com directly, my wordpress site exists.

My problem is, I have an existing domain in GoDaddy. I need this domain to go to my [sitename].wpengine.com site (while keeping my domain in the address bar). The best I could figure out is to create a forwarding record in GoDaddy. However, the performance of my site *is of the most importance*. I know there are `A`-records and `CNAME` records, but I don't fully understand those. Forwarding sounds like a wrapper which would slow things down. From my understanding, an `A`-record requires an IP Address (which I don't seem to have based on the frst paragraph). And for a `CNAME` record I'm not sure what to change. I'm concerned I'll break our email capabilities or something.

Is forwarding the correct course of action? Or is there something I can do with the `A`-and-`CNAME` records to squeeze out just a little more performance?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You're prematurely optimizing.

Do you really think DNS lookups are the slowest part of your entire website? I just did some tests against my own Wordpress site. The DNS lookup took **0.008s**, while retrieving the actual body of the page took **0.072s**. Pulling down the page is **nine times** slower, and my web server is cached by Varnish and using a static site plugin. This doesn't include downloading images, running scripts or any of the other things your browser would do.

Yes, performance optimization for DNS is possible. I can't imagine a Wordpress site would ever benefit from it.

Look up [name-based virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting). As you saw, you **must** send
 `sitename.wpengine.com` for WPEngine's servers to know which host you're requesting. Adding a CNAME from `sitename.com` to `sitename.wpengine.com` won't work in that case. You'll have to work with your host (and probably pay them more money) to get the behavior you want.

Comment: I have a boss that is very detail-oriented. He's reading stuff that says GoDaddy's DNS stuff can take up to 300ms (I don't have a source). For that reason, I'm trying to do the best I can on the DNS side to ensure that's not the problem. I do agree theres plenty of optimization on the WordPress side. I just want to address the DNS issue now if I can.

Comment: If GoDaddy's DNS slowness is an issue, don't use GoDaddy for DNS.

Comment: `He's reading stuff that says GoDaddy's DNS stuff can take up to 300ms` - Well hearsay and conjecture don't make for fact. I hate it when people take action on something based on `something they read or heard` without having cold hard facts to support their position.

Comment: I know this is old but... " Adding a CNAME from sitename.com to sitename.wpengine.com won't work in that case." This is wrong. One can either set an A record to the server IP or set a CNAME to [sitename].wpengine.com. Bother solution will work and both are mentioned in their support pages

Comment: @LyK Do you expect me to keep every answer up to date with every vendor's offering ever?

Comment: 300 milliseconds seems pretty fast, actually

Comment: @JoelESalas Not at all. I just saw it and though of mentioning the current situation. Moreover, I though this was how it was working in the past too. I guess I was wrong on that part.

Answer (score 4):

According to WPEngine, you just need a CNAME record pointing at your wpengine address. See [this](http://wpengine.com/support/how-to-set-your-dns-for-godaddy-com/) for instructions (directly from WPEngine, actually).